# Is there a better way to define const in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to define some const in my APP, Code A define this const in string resource file,

Code B define this const as top val in a kt file, and I can access it just like `const.SavedJsonName`

It's a little inconvenience to use resources in Code A, is Code B a good way?

Or do you have a better way?

**Code A**

```
<string name="SavedJsonName">mySavedJsonC</string>
```

**Code B**

```
// const.kt

val SavedJsonName="mySavedJsonC"
```

Comment: https://blog.egorand.me/where-do-i-put-my-constants-in-kotlin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach is obviously better on Android considering capability since it brings support for i18n (multi-lingual), while the second one is more efficient.

My opinion is, if it's a natural language string (like the texts displayed on UI), put them in `string.xml`. If not (like the ID for some database tables), put them in a kt file like `const.kt`.

BTW you'd better use `const val SAVED_JSON_NAME = "mySafedJsonC"` (which makes it a compile-time constant, enabling the compiler to do constant folding) instead of the code you've provided.

Comment: Thanks!  "mySavedJsonC" is a const, I don't translate it by different language.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer or tell me what information is missing in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to declare some character constants, you can use the first approach, or you can use the second approach.

Actually you can use some utils method to access these constants if you use Code A